# nginx configuration to load files without trailing slash no redirect

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I want nginx to run  /filename rendered as html file,  /folder/ as folder (I mean loading /folder/index.html), and  /filename.html as html file.

With default setup /filename not working. When I put a file as /filename to the server, it downloads the file.

I dont want any redirects, just load the files without trailing slash.

My current setup is

```
 location / {
          try_files $uri  @proxy;
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `default_type text/html;` to your server configuration.

Details of my test:

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    root    /var/www/example.com;

    default_type text/html;
}
```

Test directory structure:

```
├── afile
├── afile.html
└── afolder
    └── index.html
```

afile:

```html
<html>
<b>html with no extension</b>
</html>
```

afile.html:

```html
<html>
<b>html with an html extension</b>
</html>
```

afolder/index.html

```html
<html>
<b>index.html</b>
</html>
```